# buildbot: Triggering Schedulers & WithProperties

Tags: python, buildbot

I am trying to use the `WithProperties` in Triggering Schedulers in an add step (see this [link](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.4p2/Triggering-Schedulers.html#Triggering-Schedulers)).

I need to use the same properties whatever parent job using same has to be used in child job.

The following is a snapshot of my master configuration file:

```
sandboxfactory.addStep(
     trigger.Trigger(
     schedulerNames=['installer-job'],
     waitForFinish=True,
     WithProperties("HOST_OS=%(buildername)s")))
```

However, I am getting the following configuration error:

```
2015-11-02 09:34:48+0000 [-]    exceptions.SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg (master.cfg, line 351)
```

I tried basic configuration changes, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buildbot config is just python file, so

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b

f(a=1, 2)
```

things like this cause errors, you should write f(a=1, **b=**2) to fix this, in your case you should write `set_properties={'something': WithProperties("HOST_OS=%(buildername)s")}`